# Shorten This Code with... blocks?

Tags: objective-c

I think this code cannot be shortened much, especially because I only consider two cases. But maybe there's a language construct that I don't know that would help.

```
if (subControl.inverted) {
    newValue = subControl.value+(float)(1.0f/(float)subControl.decorator.ticks);
    if (newValue > 1)
        newValue = 0;
} else {
    newValue = subControl.value-(float)(1.0f/(float)subControl.decorator.ticks);
    if (newValue < 0)
        newValue = 1;
}
```

Some of the `(floats)` are gratuitous, which is irrelevant.

**Edit**: The code could look like this, which helps. However, I guess this is the result of reading the answers already ;)

```
if (subControl.inverted) {
    newValue = subControl.value+(float)(1.0f/(float)subControl.decorator.ticks);
} else {
    newValue = subControl.value-(float)(1.0f/(float)subControl.decorator.ticks);
}

if (newValue > 1)
    newValue = 0;
if (newValue < 0)
    newValue = 1;
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not a lot shorter, but a bit...

```
float ticks = (float)(1.0f/(float)subControl.decorator.ticks);
newValue = subControl.value + subControl.inverted ? ticks : - ticks;

if (subControl.inverted && newValue > 1)  {
    newValue = 0;
} else if (!subControl.inverted && newValue < 0){
    newValue = 1;
}
```

You could make it even shorter if the you are restricting the values to just 0 and 1.

EDIT: you say in a comment, that it should be between 0 and 1, so...

```
if (newValue > 1)  {
    newValue = 0;
} else if (newValue < 0){
    newValue = 1;
}
```

Which is fewer characters if not fewer lines, and imo clearer in intent.

Comment: Really, I might even be able to simplify the last bit, since `newValue = MAX(0, newValue)` and `newValue = MIN(1, newValue)` regardless of whether it's inverted or not. I mean, the thing is constrained to 0 to 1 and flips at end of range. So your code is really tight and, thanks to using one more variable, really easy to read.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't mind using the [ternary operator](http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/Objective-C_Operators_and_Expressions#The_Ternary_Operator), I suppose you could do something like this:

```
if (subControl.inverted) {
    newValue = subControl.value+(float)(1.0f/(float)subControl.decorator.ticks);
    newValue = newValue > 1 ? 0 : newValue;
} else {
    newValue = subControl.value-(float)(1.0f/(float)subControl.decorator.ticks);
    newValue = newValue < 0 ? 1 : newValue;
}
```

Or shorten it further to:

```
newValue = subControl.value + (subControl.inverted?1:-1) * (float)(1.0f/(float)subControl.decorator.ticks);
if (subControl.inverted) {
    newValue = newValue > 1 ? 0 : newValue;
} else {
    newValue = newValue < 0 ? 1 : newValue;
}
```

And if you really want to get funky:

```
newValue = subControl.value + (subControl.inverted?1:-1) * (float)(1.0f/(float)subControl.decorator.ticks);
newValue = subControl.inverted ? (newValue > 1 ? 0 : newValue)
                               : (newValue < 0 ? 1 : newValue);
```

...Not that I think this last version is good - it's a bit harder to follow, and I probably wouldn't use it myself. But it's shorter, which is what you wanted, and I don't know if I can make it any shorter.

---

If this were golf, here would be the hole-in-one:

```
newValue = subControl.inverted ? ((subControl.value + (subControl.inverted?1:-1) * (float)(1.0f/(float)subControl.decorator.ticks))> 1 ? 0 : ((subControl.value + (subControl.inverted?1:-1) * (float)(1.0f/(float)subControl.decorator.ticks))< 0 ? 1 : (subControl.value + (subControl.inverted?1:-1) * (float)(1.0f/(float)subControl.decorator.ticks))) );
```

cleaned up a bit:

```
newValue = subControl.inverted ?
               (
                  (subControl.value + (subControl.inverted?1:-1) * (float)(1.0f/(float)subControl.decorator.ticks))> 1
                  ? 0
                  :
                    (
                      (subControl.value + (subControl.inverted?1:-1) * (float)(1.0f/(float)subControl.decorator.ticks))< 0
                      ? 1
                      :
                        (subControl.value + (subControl.inverted?1:-1) * (float)(1.0f/(float)subControl.decorator.ticks))
                    )
              );
```

And remember: Just because you *can* doesn't mean you *should!*

(I haven't tested this last one, BTW)

Comment: Fascinating, I didn't know (or remember) that the ternary operator is so versatile. The last one isn't SO bad, really.

Comment: As I said down below to @jmoreno, I really don't care whether it's inverted or not in the last part: if it's past one it's always 0 (loops around) and if it's below 0 it's 1 (same).

Comment: @Yar: Would it be correct to say in English "If newValue is positive OR zero, then set it to 1, ELSE (if negative) set it to 1"?

Comment: No! The new value could be between zero and one. I just want it to wrap around if it's beyond the limits.

Comment: @Yar: If it's between 0 and 1, it's still a positive value. Oh wait, I think the English translation should have been: "If newValue is larger than 1, then set it to 0, ELSE (if less than 0) set it to 1"

Comment: Yes that's what I wanted.

Answer (score 1):

I think the code you posted (*first version*) is the most readable version of what you're trying to do, and that's really more important than getting your code smaller.

The only thing I would change is, [as jmoreno suggested](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/10238/8891), use a variable to hold the `ticks` and then add or subtract depending on the value of `inverted`. But I would keep the `if` blocks as you have them in the first version of your code.

Comment: I agree. My code is also more efficient than my second version (in the edit to my question) which would run both `if`. Obviously it's VERY unlikely that saving an `if` matters in terms of performance, but it's a point to keep in mind.